# android progress bar for json response

Tags: android, json

I'm new to android and i manage to make the folowing code for downloading information into my phone app from a website :

```
public class Ws_Download_KJ extends AsyncTask<Object, Boolean, String> {
    Adapter_Descarca callerActivity;
    private Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    private DataBase_MeniuDreapta sursa_sql;

     public Ws_Download_KJ(Activity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
            this.context = activity;
            this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            this.dialog.setTitle("Downloading");
            this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(true);
            if(!this.dialog.isShowing()){
                this.dialog.show();
            }
        }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String serviceUrl = (String) params[0];
        callerActivity = (Adapter_Descarca) params[1];
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = (List<NameValuePair>) params[2];
        BasicWebService webService = new BasicWebService(serviceUrl);
        webService.nameValuePairs=nameValuePairs;
        return webService.webGet();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        JSONArray jArray;

        sursa_sql = new DataBase_MeniuDreapta(activity);
        sursa_sql.open();
        sursa_sql.sterge_kj();
        try
        {   
            jArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            { 
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                sursa_sql.insert_kj(json_data.getString("salvare"));
            }
            sursa_sql.finalizare_kj();
            sursa_sql.close();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error: ", " "+e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onPostExecute(response);
    }

}
```

My application is connecting to a website throw this class and recive a json resonse. The json response is containing statements of sql insert like :

```
insert into table values (....),(....),(....) ....
insert into table values (....),(....),(....) ....
```

My question and hope you can help me is :
How can i transform my dialog box from what i have to a progress bar. What to add or modify.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

To show a Progress to the user you can use the ProgressDialogs Methods
Here's some sample code from one of my Apps:

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
mProgressDialog.show();

mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//set the max value for the dialog
mProgressDialog.setMax(fileTableCursor.getCount());
for(int i = 0; i < fileTableCursor.getCount(); i++) {
    //set the progress
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(i+1);
}
//dismiss ProgressDialog after work is done
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

I'm using the ProgressDialog in an Activity. You can use the AsyncTasks `onProgressUpdate` to set your Progress, because you can't access the UI from your `doinBackground`Thread.

Hope this helps :)